# How to download music javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I tryed to use href but its only redirected me to a web player.

```
<span><a download class="btn btn-action ml-auto mr-4 btn-sm waves-effect waves-light"  download="audio.mp3" onclick="downloadMusic()" style="background-color: #F50057;"><i class="fas fa-download pl-1"></i></a></li></span>

    function downloadMusic() {
      location.href = audiolink;
  }
```

Comment: Read the documentation about the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Where `audiolink` comes from? Also, you have 2 `download` attributes.

Comment: instead call a javascript function, just add the link to the `a href`. it's should look like this: `<a href="https://link/to/path.mp3" download="filename.mp3">download</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
There isn't much reason to use JavaScript here unless you wanna change what location of the audio file is depending on some other statement. If so, you'll have to change the button to that new audio link before the user clicks on it, the JS to change the link would be something like:

```js
function setDownloadLink() {
  document.getElementById('downloadbutton').innerHTML = '<a href="https://example.com/audio.mp3" download="audio.mp3">Download</a>'
  //You would need an element around the hyperlink with an ID, then you replace 'downloadbutton' with that ID.
}
```

If you're not wanting to have it update along with other JavaScript, then you can just do something like:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/audio.mp3" download="audio.mp3">Download</a>
```